# Apply analogous function to different elements of list based on character vector

Tags: r, list, for-loop, apply

I have one data frame (`subset_df`) that looks like the following:

```
structure(list(sequence = c("CSPPPPSPSPHPRPP", "GEGSPTSPTSPKQPG", 
"EAGAPAGSGAPPPAD", "PAPPKPKESKEPENA", "AKPKQQDEDPDGAAE", "AYATMLKDVQWKVRKS", 
"HEKLVQDIWKKLEAKG", "SCSVKLGLWKNAVNNC", "MAYVCELGPNQGWK", "LKDPKQYQSIVDAEWK", 
"KEAPGATEKDRAKATP", "TAYIMRPLDHGADVTL", "CVTQEHFREAMAKTNP", "AGTGFPYREMMPMNAP", 
"HKKSTEDNDDDAFCAP", "RPGGPPGYRTPYTAK", "TQGDRQKIQDAVSAA", "EVKSRYNVDVSQNKR", 
"VIEMTRAFEDDDFDK", "GSADLTPSNLTRPAS"), group = c("BP", "BP", 
"BP", "BP", "BP", "EpQ", "EpQ", "EpQ", "EpQ", "EpQ", "abc", "abc", 
"abc", "abc", "abc", "LbT", "LbT", "LbT", "LbT", "LbT")), .Names = c("sequence", 
"group"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Eventually, I want to create a new column (`subset_df$ID`) with an ID based on each entry under `subset_df$sequence`, following the pattern:

- group_number_first four characters under `subset_df$sequence`.

To illustrate, below I am pasting a few examples:

```
"BP_1_CSPP"  "BP_2_GEGS"  "BP_3_EAGA"  "BP_4_PAPP"  "BP_5_AKPK"  "EpQ_1_AYAT"
```

I am using the function `str_sub` from the package `stringr`to produce the output (please see loops below).

What I have done so far is the following:

```
# define where the groups are (BP, abc, LbT, EpQ)
groups <- c("BP", "EpQ", "abc", "LbT")

# define the indexes of all groups using a loop
groups_indexes <- list()
for(i in groups) {
  groups_indexes[[i]] <- grep(pattern = i, x = subset_df$group)
}
```

Considering my list (`groups_indexes`) output:

```
$BP
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$EpQ
[1]  6  7  8  9 10

$abc
[1] 11 12 13 14 15

$LbT
[1] 16 17 18 19 20
```

I only managed to do the job using one `for loop` for each element in `groups_indexes`, as shown below (four `for loops`)

```
# BP
for(i in groups_indexes[1]) {
  subset_df$IDs[i] <- paste0("BP_", i, "_", str_sub(string = subset_df$sequence[i], start = 1, end = 4))
}

# EpQ
for(i in groups_indexes[2]) {
  subset_df$IDs[i] <- paste0("EpQ_", i-(groups_indexes$EpQ[1])+1, "_", str_sub(string = subset_df$sequence[i], start = 1, end = 4))
}

# abc
for(i in groups_indexes[3]) {
  subset_df$IDs[i] <- paste0("abc_", i-(groups_indexes$abc[1])+1, "_", str_sub(string = subset_df$sequence[i], start = 1, end = 4))
}

# LbT
for(i in groups_indexes[4]) {
  subset_df$IDs[i] <- paste0("LbT_", i-(groups_indexes$LbT[1])+1, "_", str_sub(string = subset_df$sequence[i], start = 1, end = 4))
}
```

After running these four `for loops`separately, I got the following output:

```
> subset_df$IDs
 [1] "BP_1_CSPP"  "BP_2_GEGS"  "BP_3_EAGA"  "BP_4_PAPP"  "BP_5_AKPK"  "EpQ_1_AYAT" "EpQ_2_HEKL" "EpQ_3_SCSV" "EpQ_4_MAYV" "EpQ_5_LKDP"
[11] "abc_1_KEAP" "abc_2_TAYI" "abc_3_CVTQ" "abc_4_AGTG" "abc_5_HKKS" "LbT_1_RPGG" "LbT_2_TQGD" "LbT_3_EVKS" "LbT_4_VIEM" "LbT_5_GSAD"
```

However, I am trying to use a single loop to do this job. I though about using `names(groups_indexes[i])` to call the characters in quotations in my `for loops` ("BP", "EpQ", "abc", "LbT").

Comment: Please don’t add tags to the title of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps we need to group by 'group' and then `paste` the 'group' with the sequence of rows (`row_number()`) and the substring of the 'sequence (`substr`)

```
library(dplyr)
subset_df %>% 
       group_by(group) %>% 
       mutate(ID = paste(group, row_number(), substr(sequence, 1, 4), sep="_"))
#          sequence group         ID
#              <chr> <chr>      <chr>
#1   CSPPPPSPSPHPRPP    BP  BP_1_CSPP
#2   GEGSPTSPTSPKQPG    BP  BP_2_GEGS
#3   EAGAPAGSGAPPPAD    BP  BP_3_EAGA
#4   PAPPKPKESKEPENA    BP  BP_4_PAPP
#5   AKPKQQDEDPDGAAE    BP  BP_5_AKPK
#6  AYATMLKDVQWKVRKS   EpQ EpQ_1_AYAT
#7  HEKLVQDIWKKLEAKG   EpQ EpQ_2_HEKL
#8  SCSVKLGLWKNAVNNC   EpQ EpQ_3_SCSV
#9    MAYVCELGPNQGWK   EpQ EpQ_4_MAYV
#10 LKDPKQYQSIVDAEWK   EpQ EpQ_5_LKDP
#11 KEAPGATEKDRAKATP   abc abc_1_KEAP
#12 TAYIMRPLDHGADVTL   abc abc_2_TAYI
#13 CVTQEHFREAMAKTNP   abc abc_3_CVTQ
#14 AGTGFPYREMMPMNAP   abc abc_4_AGTG
#15 HKKSTEDNDDDAFCAP   abc abc_5_HKKS
#16  RPGGPPGYRTPYTAK   LbT LbT_1_RPGG
#17  TQGDRQKIQDAVSAA   LbT LbT_2_TQGD
#18  EVKSRYNVDVSQNKR   LbT LbT_3_EVKS
#19  VIEMTRAFEDDDFDK   LbT LbT_4_VIEM
#20  GSADLTPSNLTRPAS   LbT LbT_5_GSAD
```

If we the numbers are not by group and based on the whole column, then remove the `group_by` operation and just do

```
subset_df %>%
     mutate(ID = paste(group, row_number(), substr(sequence, 1, 4), sep="_"))
```